# PowerShell: System.Object or PSObject?

Tags: powershell

I have recently started using custom objects inside a few of my PowerShell scripts. Upon looking around online I noticed that there are two ways to create these objects

```
$Obj1 = New-Object System.Object
$Obj2 = New-Object PSObject
```

They both have the functionality that I needed, such as setting custom properties for necessary information to be held.

My question is, is there a necessary time to use one of them over the other? I found an article on Technet that seems to be heading in the right direction to giving an answer to this question, but I haven't been able to wrap my mind around it. Link is below.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/dcfa43ba-812f-4274-b5b2-caa0e2d56988/psobject-vs-systemobject?forum=ITCG

Thanks!

Comment: Use the modern (PS3+) syntax `$obj = [PSCustomObject]@{a=1; b=2}`

Comment: PSObject is inherited from System.Object.  It will have more members by default.

Comment: I usually only see `System.Object` used in parameter definitions where you want to express "this parameter accepts objects of arbitrary type", since `System.Object` is the common base class for virtually any object. I can't think of a reason for using `New-Object -Type Object` instead of `New-Object -Type PSObject` (which actually creates `PSCustomObject` objects) for the construction of custom objects.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers *which actually creates `PSCustomObject` objects* `PSCustomObject` is a singleton class it have only [one instance](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master@%7B2017-07-28%7D/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/MshObject.cs#L2367). `New-Object` do not create them.

Comment: Thank you all for your input, I found another article which made this topic more clear!

https://cjoprey.wordpress.com/archived/custom-object-gotchas/

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers For clarity, both the `[psobject]` and `[pscustomobject]` type accelerators boil down to the `System.Management.Automation.PSObject` type. I'm unsure what gives `[pscustomobject]` its unique typecasting, though. `System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject` does not have a public constructor, but instantiating `psobject` results in one.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Compare `([PSObject]@{'foo'='bar'}).GetType().FullName`, `([PSCustomObject]@{'foo'='bar'}).GetType().FullName`, and `(New-Object -Type PSObject -Property ${'foo'='bar'}).GetType().FullName`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers That's due to parser magic more than it is due to the type accelerator.  `[psobject]` is `[pscustomobject]`.  I'm still not certain why calling the `psobject` constructor results in a `System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject` type

Comment: That I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find my answers in the article linked below.

[Custom-Object-Gotchas](https://cjoprey.wordpress.com/archived/custom-object-gotchas/)

As a side note, the answer I was looking for was that it seems PSObject is not limited as System.Object is in terms of using them with .NET functions. A System.Object will not pass custom properties to .NET functions but a PSObject will